# SwiftUI receiving "Editor placeholder in source file" and "Protocol 'Equatable' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself" errors

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm taking a SwiftUI course and am trying to get this animation method figured out and for some reason it's not compiling.

Haven't coded in a while with swift, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

```
 struct ContentView: View {
private let imageURL: String = "https://credo.academy/credo-academy@3x.png"

var body: some View {

    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageURL), transaction: Transaction(animation: .interactiveSpring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0.25))) {
        phase in
        switch phase {
        case .success(let image):
            image
                .imageModifier()
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        case .failure(_):
            Image(systemName: "ant.circle.fill").iconModifier()
        case.empty:
            Image(systemName: "photo.circle.fill").iconModifier()
        @unknown default:
           ProgressView()
        }
    }
    .padding(40)
}
  }
```

Comment: The issue is not in this code - if I comment your custom image modifiers (not provided) then all compiled fine.

Comment: When you use autocomplete on Xcode for example a function then you get placeholders for the values you need to supply yourself, if you leave a placeholder untouched in the code and compile then you get the error in the title

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the issue was fixed by restarting xcode